# EF6 Lazy Loading not working for a navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've got 2 new entities in an otherwise working app, I've trimmed unrelated properties (everything is marked virtual):

QuoteOverrideRequest

```
public virtual int RequestedById { get; set; }
public virtual int QuoteId { get; set; }
public virtual int StatusId { get; set; }

//nav properties
public virtual Customer RequestedBy { get; set; }
public virtual Quote Quote { get; set; }
public virtual QuoteOverrideRequestStatus Status { get; set; }
```

All 3 navigation properties are mapped the same way.  When I create a new QuoteOverrideRequest and insert it, RequestedBy and Quote are auto populated with their entities.  Status is not.

```
QuoteOverrideRequest request = new QuoteOverrideRequest();
request.QuoteId = quoteId;
request.RequestedById = _workContext.CurrentCustomer.Id;
request.StatusId = 1;

_quoteService.InsertOverrideRequest(request);
```

The insert function is calling a Repository that adds the object to a DbSet and calls the DbContext.SaveChanges()

I assume the problem is with QuoteOverrideRequestStatus because the other 2 classes lazy load correctly.  If I get an instance of that Status earlier in the function, it will show up in the Status property after the insert.

The QuoteOverrideRequestStatus class has a public parameterless constructor and all of it's properties are virtual.

```
public partial class QuoteOverrideRequestStatus : BaseEntity
{
    public QuoteOverrideRequestStatus() { }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
}
```

BaseEntity has the Id property.  I've confirmed that Lazy Loading and Proxy Generation are both true on the DbContext when all this runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new QuoteOverrideRequest()`

This is not correct. Lazy loading won't work for properties of models you instantiate using the `new` keyword.

You should use `db.Set<T>().Create()` where `db` is your instance of `DbContext` and `T` is your model.

This will instantiate the correct proxy object of your model which will enable lazy-loading navigation properties.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I was getting throw off because two of the properties would load correctly but I just realized it was because they were already in the context for other reasons.  Once I switched RequestedById to someone else, it wouldn't load.  Now that I'm instantiating the entity this way, it all works.  Thanks.